# Unity, C#, and iTween

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, itween

I have a script which makes an object rotate when you click on it. I would like to see if adding iTween to it would improve the motion, but where should I add it?

iTween code:

```
iTween.RotateBy(gameObject, iTween.Hash("x", .25, "easeType", "easeInOutBack", "loopType", "pingPong", "delay", .4));
```

Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour {

    public float minX = -360.0f;
    public float maxX = 360.0f;

    public float minY = -3660.0f;
    public float maxY = 360.0f;

    public float sensX = 500.0f;
    public float sensY = 500.0f;

    float rotationY = 0.0f;
    float rotationX = 0.0f;

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            rotationX += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * sensX * Time.deltaTime;
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * sensY * Time.deltaTime;
            rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minY, maxY);
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (rotationY, -rotationX, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you wish to replace your existing rotation code to use the iTween function like this?

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
        iTween.RotateBy(gameObject, iTween.Hash("x", .25, "easeType", "easeInOutBack", "loopType", "pingPong", "delay", .4));
    }
}
```